# How to restart service in android to call service oncreate again

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service in my Android Application which runs always.Now i have a settings from my server through GCM and update these settings to my service. I put my settings in oncreate of service. So i need to restart my service to fetch latest settings.  How to restart my service?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Call this two methods right after each other, which will causes the `Service` to stop and start. Don't know any method that "restarts" it. This is how I have implemented it in my application.

```
stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
```

Comment: I have tried this method,actually i restarted service inside a broadcast receiver which is registered in onCreate() of Service. After the broadcast receiver received message,then my service onDestroy() method called multiple times and service running again and again.

Comment: So you will get in forever going loop, you should re-think your structure then.

Comment: @EduardoPoço correct. Most of the times it doesnt work. Any work around ?

Comment: Does this solution not have a race condition since intents are asynchronous?

Answer (score 16):

The best solution is to use onDestroy().

When need to restart the service just call

```
RESTARTSERVICE = true;
stopService(new Intent(this, CLASS_OF_SERVICE.class));
```

and

```
public void onDestroy()
{
   if (RESTARTSERVICE)
    {
       startService(new Intent(this, CLASS_OF_SERVICE.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution and worked for me in my Delphi Android Host-Service app too.

Comment: This "onDestroy()" method is called from Service or called from Activity? because Service and Activity have 2 different threads that can't access to the same static variables. (with same instance or values or whatever is called)

Comment: Note that this might result in the service not being completely shut down before being started up again

Answer (score 4):

Why not move the setting stuff from onCreate to a separate method. You can then call this method from onCreate and also call it when you need to change the settings. Then there would be no need to actually restart the service.

Comment: I done some conditional checking operations and start some other service based on that.If i do like this,those operations execute repeatedly.

Comment: OK, that wasn't mentioned. Then perhaps restarting the service _is_ the best idea. But I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Method onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)  inside service, hence the service restarted again

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    System.out.println("service in onTaskRemoved");
    long ct = System.currentTimeMillis(); //get current time
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            PushService.class);
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 0, restartService,
            0);

    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ct, 1 * 1000, restartServicePI);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In KOTLIN you can do it like this:

```
        AppLog.i("System UI Service is Restarting")
        val startSystemUiIntent = Intent(context, AwesomeService::class.java)
        val restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, startSystemUiIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis(), restartServicePendingIntent)


        stopService(Intent(context, SystemUIService::class.java))
```

Comment: Later addition: use `AlarmManagerCompat` and use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` instead of `setExact()` on current Android versions (exact requires extra permissions).

Answer (score -1):

or you can use a delayed handler to start the service. The handler will need to be declared static in a singleton, so its reference is not killed while restarting:

```
serviceRestartHandler = new Handler ();
serviceRestartHandler.postDelayed (new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                startService (new Intent (mContext, YourWonderfulService.class)
                        .putExtra (flagName, true));
                serviceRestartHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages (null);
            }
        }, 1000);
        stopSelf ();
```

Answer (score -7):

Just calling again `startService()` will start the service again if it's already running, meaning service will be restarted.

Comment: Calling startService() will NOT restart the service if it is already running.  Use the method by @Carnal.