# Restarting my android service

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I want to stop my service completely and run it again programmatically by itself. but as it called OnDestroy() or stopSelf() methods, it can not start again. 
how can i restart my service, any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried and seen this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227697/how-to-restart-service-in-android-to-call-service-oncreate-again

Answer (score 0):

I am using this way in my apps :

Stopping service :

```
mContext.stopService(new Intent(mContext, LocationProviderService.class));
```

Starting service :

```
if(!HelperUtils.isMyServiceRunning(LocationProviderService.class, getApplicationContext()))
  {
      startService(new Intent(this, LocationProviderService.class));
  }
```

isMyServiceRunning method :

```
public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context mContext) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi
Where is you use Starting service method ?

Comment: @Tony you can use [Context.StartService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startService(android.content.Intent))

Comment: i mean , where is you use !HelperUtils.isMyServiceRunning code  ?
After stopService ?

Comment: @Tony it is a check before starting service.

Comment: 1. stop service
2. if(!HelperUtils.isMyServiceRunning)

is it sequential action ?