# How to properly restart an Android service at exception?

Tags: android, android-things

I am trying to develop an Android Service that can automatically restart at exceptions.

1. I have tried adding `return START_STICKY;` on the `onStartCommand` method. But since the exception will not cause the service to crash, it won't automatically restart.
2. I have also tried the methods mentioned in [How to restart service in android to call service oncreate again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227697/how-to-restart-service-in-android-to-call-service-oncreate-again), like putting together the following code, but after `onDestory()`was called, only `onCreate()` is executed but not `onStartCommand()`

   ```
   stopService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
   startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
   ```

Right now, the service looks like this:

```
public class PostService extends Service {

    site.bdsc.raspberry_gps_test.sim800Cutil.Sim800Manager Sim800Manager;
    private Thread thTestPost;
    private boolean mRunning;
    private static String TAG = "PostService";

    public PostService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        //get service
        thTestPost = new Thread(testPost,"testPost");
        Log.d(TAG,"Service on create");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        if (!mRunning) {
            // Prevent duplicate service
            mRunning = true;
            Log.d(TAG,"Starting Post Service");
            try {
                Sim800Manager = Sim800ManagerImpl.getService("UART0");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                restartService(); //want to restart service here
            }
            thTestPost.start();
        }else{
            Log.d(TAG,"Duplicated Start Request！");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"Service on destory");
        mRunning = false;
        thTestPost.interrupt();
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private Runnable testPost = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
         // some code
        }
    };

    private void restartService(){
        stopService(new Intent(this, PostService.class));
        startService(new Intent(this,PostService.class));
    }
}
```

As shown in the code, I want the `PostService` to properly restart when `IOException` is caught.

Comment: this.stopSelf(); on IoException after this start service again

Comment: @GaneshPokale the problem is it is not re-starting itself after ```stopSelf()```

Comment: Try calling `this.stopSelf()` in the _catch_ block and `startService(new Intent(this,PostService.class))` in `onDestroy()` after `super.onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Onik  You got it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this   **START_REDELIVER_INTENT**

```
public static final int START_REDELIVER_INTENT
```

> Constant to return from `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int):` if this
>   service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from
>   `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int))`, then it will be scheduled for a
>   restart and the last delivered Intent re-delivered to it again via
>   `onStartCommand(Intent, int, int).`

Comment: Not working. The service isn't re-starting itself after ```onDestory()```

Comment: @SamYu try to call `restartService()` method inside your `onDestory()`